# How to map $\{0,1\}^n$ to $\binom{\{1, \cdots, n'\}}{n''}$ nontrivially?

Tags: combinatorics

In trying to cook up a toy/reference implementation of a [Lamport signature](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2016/12/Constructing-Digital-Signatures-from-a-One-Way-Function.pdf), I've run into the following puzzle:

The author requires, to generate a signature, a one-way function $G:M\to \binom{\{1, \cdots, n'\}}{n''}$; that is, to map messages to $n''$-element subsets of the user's $n'$-element key.

- The author himself only bothered to propose an awkward partial function based on iterative integer division with few usefulness guarantees
- Other implementers have proposed functions that constrain $n'=2n''$ and use each bit of an $n:=n''$-bit digest of the message to select from each pair of elements $(k_{2i-1}, k_{2i})$ of the user's key

However, I'm wondering if there is a *bijective* function that exists for this (likely imposing a different constraint on the values of $n'$ and $n''$). The author himself "hope[s] that someone can find a more elegant method" for this mapping.

---

So if there are exactly $\binom{n'}{n''}$ possible signatures that might be produced—which are $n''$-element subsets of an $n'$-element Lamport key—and we assume that $G$ will be constructed from an existing $n$-bit cryptographic hash function $\phi_n$—which will have a range of $\left\{0,1\right\}^n$—I suppose the question of whether any bijective construction of $G$ from $\phi_n$ exists reduces to the question of whether any natural-number solutions to this exist:

$$2^n=\binom{n'}{n''}$$

Wolfram Alpha [suggests](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2+%5E+n+%3D+%28a+choose+b%29+over+the+natural+numbers) some trivial, small solutions (such as $(3,8,7)$) but I'm unclear whether solutions to this exist with the following criteria-

- at the scale of cryptographic usefulness ($n\sim256$)
- nontrivially ($n'-n''>1,n''>1$)

Do any such solutions exist? What are some examples, or a canonical example? (Have I even proposed the right equation?—If not, ditto the above, but for the *appropriate* equation for the case of constructing $G$ for a Lamport signature.)

Comment: It is easy to define an _injection_ $\{0,1\}^n\to \binom{[n']}{n''}$ whenever $2^n<\binom{n'}{n''}$, using [combinadics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system).

Comment: @eyeballfrog Good eye, but he's looking for a **proof** of proposition he is certain of; I am looking for **examples** of fitting solutions to this equation, as well as **verification** that I'm even asking the right question. (I'll update the question to clarify.)

Comment: You formulated the question correctly. This is a duplicate, since the other question proves there are no nontrivial examples, providing an answer to your question in the negative.